# Calling Core-Foundation methods from Swift

Tags: swift, core-foundation

I'm familiar with Obj-c and getting familiar with Swift, but I'm having a horrendous time struggling with Swift's very strict type-checking. Case in point, all I wanted to do was convert the routine in Obj-c below:

```
- (void)receiveIncomingConnectionNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    NSFileHandle *incomingFileHandle = [userInfo objectForKey:NSFileHandleNotificationFileHandleItem];

    if (incomingFileHandle) {
        CFDictionaryAddValue(
            incomingRequests,
            (__bridge const void *)(incomingFileHandle),
            (__bridge const void *)((__bridge id)CFHTTPMessageCreateEmpty(kCFAllocatorDefault, TRUE)));
    }
}
```

To this in Swift:

```
func receiveIncomingConnectionNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo: NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    let incomingFileHandle: NSFileHandle? = userInfo.objectForKey(NSFileHandleNotificationFileHandleItem) as? NSFileHandle
    if (incomingFileHandle != nil) {
        CFDictionaryAddValue(self.incomingRequests as CFMutableDictionaryRef, incomingFileHandle, CFHTTPMessageCreateEmpty(kCFAllocatorDefault, true))
    }
}
```

But the CFDictionaryAddValue call keeps generating errors pointing to the 'true' parameter that says "`Cannot convert the expression's type '(CFMutableDictionaryRef, NSFileHandle?, Unmanaged<CFHTTPMessage>!' to type BooleanLiteralConvertible!`.

Anyone know the correct way to do this, or what a BooleanLiteralConvertible is?

Comment: How is `incomingRequests` declared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be clearer if you consider the arguments one at a time:

```
let m = CFHTTPMessageCreateEmpty(kCFAllocatorDefault, 1).takeRetainedValue()
let f = incomingFileHandle!
let d = self.incomingRequests as CFMutableDictionaryRef
CFDictionaryAddValue(d, unsafeAddressOf(f), unsafeAddressOf(m))
```

- The C Boolean must be expressed as a number.
- CFHTTPMessageCreateEmpty needs memory management, as it comes back as an Unmanaged.
- Your `incomingFileHandle` is an Optional; it needs unwrapping.
- CFDictionaryAddValue expects unsafe addresses (UnsafePointer).

Comment: Thank you, that's a big help! But if you wouldn't mind, why must I include a 'takeRetainedValue()' when the CFDictionary is set to retain values added to it?  Also, I was under the impression that an unwrapped variable was an address? Finally, why an 'unsafeAddressOf'? What's unsafe about pointing to an actual object?

Comment: You just follow your nose, if you know what I mean. For example, look at the Swift declaration of CFDictionaryAddValue: `func CFDictionaryAddValue(theDict: CFMutableDictionary!, key: UnsafePointer<Void>, value: UnsafePointer<Void>)`. Well, as you said, Swift is strict, so it won't let us pass this point unless we actually provide `UnsafePointer<Void>` objects, and there is only one way to get those, namely by calling `unsafeAddressOf`. This is exactly parallel to your `const void *` casts.

Comment: As for `takeRetainedValue()`, I already explained that. CFHTTPMessageCreateEmpty returns an Unmanaged, and you can't do anything with an Unmanaged in Swift until you've told Swift how to manage it. This is exactly parallel to your `bridge` casts. This method has "Create" in its name, so it is retained; you need to tell Swift that, or you'll leak it. (You were failing to do that in Objective-C, I notice.)